# Passing on data from Jquery to php superglobals not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, request

I am trying to pass data from my js file with Jquery to php. However, when I send the request through the browser, i get the value null back. My php class $imageurl is not set, neither is my super global $_POST. I have no idea why this occurs, cause if I set the fullimgurl through postman, my php request is fully working. I have tried to sent it back decoded and also encoded. none of it seems to work, which is weird since it works through postman.

Here is my Jquery code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js”></script>
</head>
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="loadFile(event)" >
<button name="submit" id="submit"></button>
</form>


<img src="" id="output"/>

<div id="textOutput"></div>

<script>
var imgfullurl;

$("#submit").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'test1.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { imgfullurl: imgfullurl },
        dataType: "json",
        contentType : "application/json",
        success: function (data) {
            $('#textOutput').html(data);
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    })
})


var loadFile = function(event) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(){
        var output = document.getElementById('output');
        output.src = reader.result;
        imgfullurl = reader.result;
        console.log('imageurl');
        console.log(imgfullurl);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);

};


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my php file:

```
if (isset($_POST['imgfullurl'])){
$imageurl = $_POST['imgfullurl'];
}

echo json_encode($imageurl);
```

Comment: Have you tried `echo file_get_contents("php://input");` ?

Comment: In your JavaScript, where is defined the variable `imgfullurl`? Are you sure that it is defined? Have you tried to `console.log(imgfullurl)` before to `$.ajax()`?

Comment: yes, that give me a load handler violation

Comment: @Syscall yes I did, it contains a base64 string, as it should, ill edit it to give you the rest of the js/jquery code

Comment: What if you do something like `data: JSON.stringify( {imgfullurl: imgfullurl) }` before passing it to PHP?

Comment: By this code, `imgfullurl` is empty

Comment: not at all @Pedram the onload event triggers before the button click, that sets the var imgfullurl to the base64 string, the log that triggers when i upload an image to my html page clearly logs a base64 string

Comment: Why do you ask the same question twice? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49692000/ajax-failed-to-load-post-request

Comment: did you try `var_dump($_POST);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use FormData

For example :

```
$( "#myForm" ).submit(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();

  url = $( "#myForm" ).attr( "action" );
  var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

  formData.append("yourkey", "yourvalue");

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (data) {
            if (data=='SUCCESS'){
            alert("Hi");
            //location.reload();

        }
            else

            alert("Something is Wrong !!"+data)
         }

  });
```

Comment: Can i still get the value in php by the formdata key?

Comment: Yes, If you see you can append your keys with the needed values i.e
 formData.append("imgfullurl", imgfullurl);